# Don't allow <script> tags to be modified

Tags: html, tags

Is there a way to block users from modifying the contents of `<script></script>` tags?
For example I may include a payment button with Javascript, but the smarter user would be able to modify its price by Firebux or other editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't stop a user from doing anything in their browser.

More to the fundamental point, regardless of any `script` tags or anything you display to the user, you can't stop anybody from manually crafting GET/POST/etc. requests to your site.  So even if you *could* somehow prevent someone from editing the HTML in their browser (which, again, you can't), they could still just watch the POST request and craft their own fake one with whatever data they want.

Never, ever, *ever* rely on client-side code for important business logic.  Track the prices of things in server-side code and use that value.  You can still maintain such data in client-side code (for UX purposes, mostly), but don't use it server-side without validating it against known trusted data first.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up for me.
I already managed to think up an idea how I'm going to process the payment price.
I'm using an API which supports only Javascript payment button which can be modified, and it's the only API that supports the banks I need. Well atleast it sends a $_POST to my desired .php.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that. You should always have that sort of validations on the server side, because everything that comes from the user browser may be faked.

Answer (score 0):

u need to display everything u need to the user but only pass the item id to the post.
then serverside retrieve the price and the rest of the data for the transaction.